# how to check string input like 2000-2000

Tags: python

```
inp = input('Input two distinct years in the range 1960 -- 2020:')
if inp <= '1960' or inp >='2020' or inp!='--' or inp =='2000--2000':
    print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...')
```

I got another input which is 2000--2000 and function will still print out print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...'). How can I solve it?

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: If you want two inputs, then read two separate and distinct inputs.

Comment: The condition `inp!='--'` will invalidate most inputs...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude or parse the input into two numbers. You perform string comparison which compares them alphabetically.

Comment: As for your shown code, remember that string comparisons are *exact*. You don't compare sub-strings, you compare the whole strings.

Comment: Google and learn about regular expressions and python's `re` module.

Comment: Please clarify your question - show us exactly what is your expected input format and how you expect to parse it through a [mre]. Explain in detail what is considered valid and invalid inputs

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych That's a possibility, but is more complex.

Comment: I second looking up `regex` and regular expressions, since that's probably what you need to use here. Also, this question can likely be asked to [ChatGPT](https://nat.dev/), which can give you an answer and isn't too critical about how the question is asked, unlike this site.

Comment: I really don't see the need for regex here... If the format of the input is `<num>--<num>` a simple [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to int the numbers with a try, except expression:

```
inp = input('Input two distinct years in the range 1960 -- 2020:')
inp = inp.strip() # removing spaces in the beginning and end of the inputed string
num1 = inp.split('--')[0].strip()

if not '--' in inp:
    print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...')
    exit(0)

num2 = inp.split('--')[1].strip()

try:
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    if num1 <= 1960 or num2 >= 2020:
        print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...')
except:
    print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...')
```

An other option is with regular expressions:

```
import re

inp = input('Input two distinct years in the range 1960 -- 2020:')
inp = inp.strip() # removing spaces in the beginning and end of the inputed string

if re.findall("^\d+\s?\-\-\s?\d+$", inp):
    num1 = int(inp[:4])
    num2 = int(inp[-4:])

if num1 <= 1960 or num2 >= 2020:
    print('Not a valid range of years, giving up...')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code here...
In `inp <= '1960'` you try to compare a string (text) with another

You also don't tell the code how to treat the input. If you input two numbers, it will see it as a text (like "2000--2000").
You never seperate them in your code.
The easiest workaround it to either have two seperate inputs, or create an integer with the first 4 letters (`year1=int(inp[:4]`)) and the last 4 (`year2=int(inp[-4:]`))